# Is there any way in Android Q to move an image from Gallery to another album using Java?

Tags: java, android, storage, image-gallery, android-10.0

I'm doing an app for Android using Java, and I need to move an image from Camera album to another album programmatically. It is possible in Android P and lower versions. But, I am looking for Android Q. Because of Scoped Storage concept I couldn't find any solution. I don't want to make a copy of them, I just want to move them. Is there a way to do this on Android Q?

Comment: This questions seems to be off-topic, or it lacks of details. Check here to see how to ask a good question: [ask]

Comment: @LucaMurra Thank you. I need only a basic answer. Also, I really need answer of this question. But because of your down vote I think I'll never get any answer. Thank you again.

Comment: It isn't clear if the question is about programming or how to use the gallery or your smartphone. If it's about programming it's on-topic, but we can't know which language you're using. If it's about your smartphone, it's off-topic.

Comment: Okey I understood. I am using java

Comment: Your question is how to programmatically move an image from Camera album to another album, in a `Java` Android app?

Comment: And it's about programming

Comment: Yes this is my question

Comment: And I don't know is there any way to do this on android Q because of Scoped storage

Comment: It lacks of where you searched, and what you tried, but I'll remove my -1

Comment: @LucaMurra Thank you so much. I aam going to edit my question.

Comment: Yes, also on Q, you can copy the image to another place and then delete the original.

Comment: Can you give an example? Or maybe a link? @blackapps

Comment: Have a look at posts with tag `mediastore` and you find all.

Comment: Thank you @blackapps there are various answers about it